# How to snap an android ImageView into a certain place on the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

so what I am trying to do is : using an OnTouchListener I have to snap an ImageView  into place in android when its dragged accross a certain location (another ImageView).  The dragging is working, getting the location of the second imageview is fine, just when im trying to set its location, it always gets aligned under the location.  How do I align it above the second imageview without using mImageView - 5, because then it wont work on every android screen that has more or less pixels. here is the code

```
                    int[] locXY = new int[2];
                    mImageView5.getLocationOnScreen(locXY);
                      int x1 = locXY[0];
                      int y1 = locXY[1];

                    int[] img3 = new int[2];
                    mImageView2.getLocationOnScreen(locXY);
                      int x2 = locXY[0];
                      int y2 = locXY[1];

           //if you reach the locating of imageview2 then snap into place

                    if (x1 <= x2 + 15 &&
                        y1 <= y2 + 20 &&
                        y1 >= y2 - 20 &&
                        x1 >= x2 - 15)  {

                        //do this       
                        tts.speak("You dont go there", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        mImageView5.setX(x2);
                        mImageView3.setTop(y2 + 5); //this should be -5 because it will make it go up, but i dont want to use a - or a +
                        mImageView5.setBottom(mImageView3.getTop());
                     } // end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this probably is not the best way of doing it, but what I did was I had a preset imageview that had the same Y coordinates as where I wanted this imageview to go. so I did something like this

```
            int[] locXY = new int[2];
                    mImageView5.getLocationOnScreen(locXY);
                    int x1 = locXY[0];
                    int y1 = locXY[1];

                    int[] img2 = new int[2];
                    mImageView2.getLocationOnScreen(img2);
                    int x2 = img2[0];
                    int y2 = img2[1];

                    int[] img3 = new int[2];
                    mImageView3.getLocationOnScreen(img3);
                    int x3 = img3[0];
                    int y3 = img3[1];


                    int[] img4 = new int[2];
                    mImageView16.getLocationOnScreen(img4);
                    int x4 = img4[0];
                    int y4 = img4[1];




                    Log.d("X and Y", "X and Y of imageview 5" + x2 + " " + x2+" " +y1+ " " + y2);
                    if (    x1 <= x2 + 15 && mImageView5.isEnabled() != false &&
                            y1 <= y2 + 20 &&
                            y1 >= y2 - 20 &&
                            x1 >= x2 - 15
                            )  


                    {

                        //do this

                                    tts.speak("That looks correct", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                                    mImageView5.forceLayout();
                                    mImageView5.setX(x2);
                                    mImageView5.setY(y4);
                                    mImageView5.setEnabled(false);
                                    mImageView5.bringToFront();


                    }
```

This will make the Y coordinates of imageview 16 and match the x coordinates of where I want it to go.  I worked around it but didnt really get answer the question of how to do it, just answered how to work around. I will leave open for a day or two to see if anyone can find something better